# Phonegap Plugin to edit existing file

Tags: plugins, windows-phone-8, cordova

I have had to write a plugin for phonegap to perform push notification registration for windows-phone.  One of the problems I found (perhaps the reason that no plugins exist already) was that in order to receive custom variables from the push message when it is activated.  I needed to add:

```
 private override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
      base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

      // Read NavigationContext.QueryString and stuff
 }
```

to the MainPage.xaml.cs.  While trying to create a plugin.xml file for this I noticed the following in the documentation:

```
 As with assets, if the target of a source-file would overwrite an existing file, plugman stops and reverses the installation, issues a notification about the problem, and exits with a non-zero code.
```

So the question becomes - Either: 
How can I force phonegap/plugman to overwrite an existing cs file?
How can I edit an existing cs file through plugin.cs (in the same way as with xml files)?
or failing these: 
How can I access OnNavigatedTo from my plugin that does not extend 'PhoneApplicationPage'?
How can I add a new default mainpage by only editing xml?

---

Ok, I think I've partially figured out this last question ... Couldn't find a way to force phonegap/plugman, but just writing the question "How can I add a new default mainpage" made me go back and look at it again.  I can add a new page fine and can edit WMAppManifest.xml to change the DefaultTask to my new page.  But I don't think this will work with plugman as I want to replace the existing DefaultTak rather than add a new DefaultTask to the Tasks node.. So follow-up question.. Can I edit an existing node with plugin.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer to all of the above is 'No'.  After raising this with the phonegap people, Currently this cannot be done, any fix would have to be on the code side in order to not use the base page.  Currently I am having to have a separate build for wp8.  As it is, this isn't too bad as there are a number of things that wp is useless at (the httpwebrequest does not contain a 'Date' header!! so no authentication using the date value) meaning that plugins are needed to find alternate ways of doing things.